# Cleveref not working with multiple references

Tags: cleveref

`\Cref` does not seem to be functioning properly. `\usepackage{cleveref}` (as is) is used.

`\Cref{ref1}, \Cref{ref2}` works but `\Cref{ref1, ref2}` results in only the first reference being shown, with the other as `??`

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By default, `\cref` and friends do not allow whitespace in their arguments. If you change `\Cref{ref1, ref2}` to `\Cref{ref1,ref2}`, you'll do fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably your problem is caused by the space inside your `\Cref`-command. Compare the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
   \begin{equation}\label{a}
      1+1=2
   \end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\label{b}
      2-1=1
   \end{equation}
   We used \Cref{a,b}.\\
   We used \Cref{a, b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]